# All lines in Visual Studio are squiggly red

Tags: c#

I'm sure this question has been asked before, if there's a similar question with a solution I apologize in advance. I've tried to find something similar to this in the forum already but I can't find any solutions.

So I recently swapped to a new computer. I installed Visual Studio, same version as I used previously, and I also installed .NET 7 (which I used previously aswell).

I started my project in Visual Studio and everything in my code is squiggly red. Literally everything, except the names of variables. It can't find any of the namespaces, not even System. I've tried going through the settings, re-installing NuGet packages, removing bin folders, removing packages folder etc. I can't seem to find the issue, afaik there's no major difference between my old laptop and the one I'm currently using. It's the exact same project files. The files work on my old laptop.

Not sure if I've missed something really obvious. Very thankful for any help.

Some images to showcase the error:

[image: Squiggly red lines on almost everything]

Comment: just to make sure have you downloaded the .NET7 build sdk? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0

Comment: @Roe Yes sir, I made sure I had not missed that before posting the question to avoid making a fool of myself hehe

Comment: Maybe consider sharing important parts for error analysis like csproj file.

Comment: Hit rebuild, in the build output window search for the first line saying error. what does it say?

Comment: @RandRandom Output from Build: This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.

I've tried deleting/restoring NuGet packages. It says that it has been succesful but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Check if your old laptop and new laptop have different nuget sources. Open the package manager and at top right your will find a combobox for package sources

Comment: @ˈvɔlə How do I attach files to my question?

Comment: You can't only images, you could use github and share a github link.

Comment: @RandRandom Thank you! I checked the nuget source, they're the same on both laptops!

Comment: Or just paste the file content as a code block.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hSRH.png

Comment: @RandRandom They're both set to nuget.org and both have the same alternatives.

Comment: Maybe you have different nuget versions? if you run the command "nuget" in CMD does it print the same version? And if possible share the used nuget packages. and consider checking the output window for package manager

Comment: @ˈvɔlə https://codebeautify.org/cs/b7c1bf

Comment: @RandRandom Sorry but I can't seem to run the command. Where am I supposed to run that command? Neither the CMD in Windows or the Command Window in Visual Studio properly recognizes that command.

Comment: that is also valid, means you only have nuget inside visual studio and not as an external tool, please share the packages.config file

Comment: @RandRandom https://codebeautify.org/cs/2d35c1

Comment: No problem to be found with the packages, all of them are available on my side: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l30y.png - sorry, but I have no further ideas, good luck

Comment: Just to make sure, you have the option "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" enabled in the settings? https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVJO4.png

Comment: Compile the code, if you get errors, *fix the errors*, or ask about the errors you are getting. If everything compiles fine, VS might just be having one of its moments, it might help to restart it, clean your git working directory, or to clean the visual studio temporary/cache files.

Comment: @RandRandom Yeah, I have it enabled. I'm all out of options right now.

Comment: @JonasH It doesn't allow me to compile. It gives me around 1700 errors, asking me to fix them before I can compile. Everything in my code is an error atm.

Answer (score -1):

So, seemingly after attempting everything I could find online (including the steps below), I attempted this with success:

1. Clean solution
2. Restart Visual Studio
3. Remove packages folder
4. Restore NuGet packages.
5. Rebuild solution
6. Repeat around **10** times.

If anyone has this issue and can't get it to work, just keep repeating the steps. I had to do it over 10 times before it actually worked. I'm still not sure what caused it but this was my solution.